# How to run npm install for EEXIST error

Tags: node.js, npm

When I do an npm install I get the foll

```css
node_modules                                                                                                                \wdpr-grunt-tasks\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.                                                                                                                io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-valid                                                                                                                ate>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_                                                                                                                modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
npm ERR! EEXIST, npm-cache\56f3dfab--cac                                                                                                                he-lodash-3-10-1-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: 56f3dfab--cache-lodash-                                                                                                                3-10-1-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path  ...                                                                                                              -3-10-1-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: try clearing cache for node `npm cache clean`

Comment: did that..It did not help!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to clean your npm cache with command:

`npm cache clean`

To make sure, you can delete `node_modules` folder and install all modules again.

Comment: and did you delete node_modules? Also I suggest to use newer version of NodeJS and NPM. It may help.

Comment: yep..i did all those..no help!